# Live streaming the Raspbian desktop to YouTube

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, streaming, youtube

I am looking to live stream my Raspberry Pi's desktop to YouTube. I've seen plenty of guides on streaming the Pi Camera with ffmpeg, but nothing for the desktop. Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the source `x11grab`, like so:

```
ffmpeg     -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -framerate 30 [...]
```

to grab the X frame buffer.